# tile/valueBox visualization in R that will save to png

Tags: r, shinydashboard

I would like to run some R code and obtain a series of tiles, that look like this:

[image]

Shinydashboard makes it possible to show these tiles online, but I need to embed these in a SharePoint site, so I need the output to be images (long story there on why I can't iframe an html file in).

I know it's possible to download output of Shiny objects [using this approach](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/shiny-discuss/u7gwXc8_vyY)... but I don't want to create a download button to then get the charts I want, I want to run my code and save the output as images automatically. In other words, I don't *need* to be using Shiny at all... It's just the only package I found that lets me plot this output. Is there any other package that allows for this type of output from R? If not, how can I save output from Shiny directly?

My minimal code, in case it helps:

```
library(shinydashboard)
library(shiny)

 body <- dashboardBody(
    fluidRow(
      valueBox(
        uiOutput("bens"), "Benef reg", icon = icon("users"), color = "green")
    ))

  server <- function(input, output) {
    ## beneficiaries
    output$bens <- renderText({
      prettyNum(150, big.mark=",")
    })}

  shinyApp(
    ui = dashboardPage(
      dashboardHeader(),
      dashboardSidebar(),
      body),
    server = server)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, since people are still looking at this question 5 years later, I'll add some info. Now, there are four ways to visualize single-digit information in a dashboard:

- [flexdashboard::valueBox](https://pkgs.rstudio.com/flexdashboard/reference/valueBox.html) works in normal markdown documents
- [Shinydashboard](https://rstudio.github.io/shinydashboard/structure.html#infobox) has valueBox and infoBoxes, but needs shiny to work.
- [Summarywidget](https://kent37.github.io/summarywidget/using.html) works with crosstalk in shiny and markdown
- and lastly, I created a package called [TileMaker](http://datastrategist.github.io/TileMaker/index.html) that allows for a fully-featured set of buttons based on twitter's bootstrap. Works in shiny and markdown.

Hope that helps someone! :)